# First-chance exception in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, first-chance-exception

Following is a part of my VC++ code being coded in VS2010.

```
do
{

    std:: cout << "\nOPTIONS:\n";
    std:: cout << "\n1. Get all session data.\n";
    std:: cout << "\n2. Get Nth session data\n";
    std:: cout << "\n3. Get Next session data\n";
    std:: cout << "\n4. Get Previous session data\n";
    std:: cout << "\n5. Get total no of sessions\n";
    std:: cout << "\n6. Exit\n";
    std:: cout << "\nEnter Your Option: ";

    std :: cin >> option;

    switch(int(option))
    {
         case 1:
            {
                data.ReadSetupFile();
                 break;
            }

        case 2:
            {
                break;
            }

        .....
        ......

        case 6:
            {

                std::cout<<"\nARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO EXIT?(Press y for yes and any other character for no)\n";
                cin >> opt;
                break;
            }

        default:
            {
                std::cout << "\nINAVALID OPTION!!TRY AGAIN\n";
                break;
             }

    }

    std::cout<<"\nDO YOU WANT TO CONTINUE?(Press y for yes and any other character for no)\n";
    cin >> opt;

  }while(opt=='y');
```

However, if I insert a character instead of an integer as value of `option` , the menu option is going on printed in the output console without termination until I use `ctrl+c`. On using this break strategy I get the message as :

`First-chance exception at 0x75936da7 in SetupAPIReader.exe: 0x40010005: Control-C.`

Why is the execution not terminating?

Comment: You pressed `Control-C` and ask why your program got a `Control-C` exception?

Comment: Have you setup the control handler for `Ctrl-C`?

Comment: Actually my doubt is why it is not terminating?

Comment: Also, as to the question you probably should have asked, if `std::cin >> option;` fails, `failbit` is set on the stream and all subsequent attempt to read will simply fail; hence `opt` will never be changed. You need to [check for error, `ignore()` the invalid input, and `clear()` the error state](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/istream-and-ignore.html).

Comment: @T.C. : It works properly when I supply integer value for `option`. In my logic, typecasting should convert char to integer and hence it should work properly. Isn't it?

Comment: @T.C.:  Thank you.. it worked. Is there any significance in adding ignore()? I get the same output even if ignore is ther or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the given input is not of expected type, the `failbit` of `cin` is set. Checking for this bit and clearing will reset the value to initial value of the variable.

```
if(!cin)
    {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
```